# Post increment on set iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, set

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iterator validity ,after erase() call in std::set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636578/iterator-validity-after-erase-call-in-stdset)

When I iterate over a set and want to delete certain items the iterators are changed. This results in segfaults as the iteration fails after deletion. How can I overcome this problem?

```
std::set< std::pair<double,unsigned>, comparisonFunction> candidates;'
[...]

for( auto it = candidates.begin(); it != candidates.end(); ++it)
{
  [...]
  if ( some constraint satisfied)
  {
    candidates.erase(it);
  }
}
```

I encounter a segfault when I use this code. My guess is that this is either due to the corrupted iterators or due to the fact, that the element to be deleted is the last element in some cases. Does a post increment on the iterator overcome this problem? Like this:

```
candidate.erase(it++);
```

Comment: Use the return value of `erase` as the iterator resumed value, **else** increment normally.

Comment: Possible Dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636578/iterator-validity-after-erase-call-in-stdset

Comment: `candidates.erase( remove_if( candidates.begin(), candidates.end() ), [](){ some constraint satisfied } ), candidates.end() );`

Comment: You may not even get a segmentation fault. Simply put, this code and approach is wrong. The way to solve the issue is not to use an iterator that has been invalidated. Fortunately, `std::set::erase` already has a return value that allows you to work around the problem -- read its documentation for further information.

Comment: @Caribou: I'd like to take back my exact duplicate vote. This isn't. The other question had a special case for removing every element in the set. Additionally, none of the answers take C++11 into account.

Comment: @Omnifarious thats true - the ref may help the OP anyway.

Comment: @K-ballo: Since C++11 `std::set::iterator` is a **constant** bidirectional iterator. I hardly believe that remove_if can operate on this. Also, if this was possible you would destroy the `log N` complexity of `find()`.

Comment: @Zeta: Is this enforced by types? Or are we to expect a slew of quietly broken code like that in the coming years? I vaguely recall that set iterators have non-`const` albeit non-mutable value types, which would make K-ballo's broken code pass compilation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: According to N3376 the `std::set::iterator` is implementation defined, however, if I recall correctly `std::set` is often implemented as a Red-Black-Tree. Using `std::remove_if` shouldn't work, since the traversal of a set returns its elements with respect to the comparison function, and `std::remove_if` would destroy this as it would destroy the rbtree property. Also note that it won't compile (gcc 4.7.2): `Error: Assignment of write-only memory address »__result.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator*<double>()«`

Comment: @Zeta: I guess we just have to hope then that in all implementations for which this is the case, `const` is used properly to signal such broken code at compile-time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the return value of `erase`:

```
it = candidates.erase(it);
```

Note that you must not increment `it` if you erase an element, otherwise your iterator could be invalidated.

```
for( auto it = candidates.begin(); it != candidates.end();)
{
  if ( some constraint satisfied)
  {
    it = candidates.erase(it);
  }
  else
    ++it;
}
```

Also note that this wasn't possible in C++03, since `erase` didn't return any iterator. However, since you're using C++11 it shouldn't be a problem.

#### References

- [`std::set::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase)